# How to leave gaps while dragging down

Tags: google-sheets

I have `=A1` on one cell and then a bunch of text on three cells beneath it and then `=A2` on the fourth cell beneath it, how to make sure that when I drag down, it goes to `A3` after leaving three cells and so forth?

Comment: Welcome. The question doesn't show your search/research efforts. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask] to learn part of the basics of this site.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the following:

- D1 refers to A1
- D4 refers to A2
- D7 refers to A3

and so on, use a formula such as `=offset(A$1, row(D1)/3, 0)` in cell D1. This offsets the reference to A1 by the row number divided by 3 (the result is rounded down automatically). When copied down the column, it will offset the cell positions correctly.